# Signalr: firsttime user, cannot get 'server button event' to 'hub' to 'client' to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, signalr

hey guys I am trying out siqnalr for the first time and am having some issues getting it to work.

I can get the client to call the hub method with no issues.
I can get the hub to call the client with no issues.
But I want to call the hub from my server side button click event so I can update the client with processing info but no matter what I try I cannot get it to work.

does anyone have any ideas?

I am probably missing some thing simple but I have no idea what is wrong.

here is my code:

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
    }
```

TestHub.cs

```
  using System;
  using System.Linq;
  using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

    namespace Hubs
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Summary description for TestHub
        /// </summary>
        public class TestHub : Hub
        {

            public void Send(string name, string message)
            {
                // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
                Clients.Caller.broadcastMessage(name, message);
            }


            internal static void Send2(string name, string message)
            {

                //test 1
                IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TestHub>();
                context.Clients.All.Send(name, message);

                //test 2
                IHubContext context2 = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TestHub>();
                context2.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);

            }

        }

    }
```

default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Signalr2._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>


<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" Runat="server">
            <Scripts>

                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js" />     

                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.2.js"/> 
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/signalr/hubs"  />  

            </Scripts>
        </telerik:RadScriptManager>

        <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="RadScriptBlock1" runat="server">

            <script type="text/javascript">

                $(function ()
                {
                    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
                    var ifiHub = $.connection.testHub;

                    // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
                    ifiHub.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message)
                    {

                        // Html encode display name and message. 
                        var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                        var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();

                        // Add the message to the page. 
                        $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
                    };

                    //Start the connection.
                    $.connection.hub.start().done(function ()
                    {
                        ifiHub.server.send('connection started:', $.connection.hub.id);
                    });
                });

            </script>

        </telerik:RadScriptBlock>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Server To Client Test" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <br /><br />
        <ul id="discussion"/>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace Signalr2
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //test 1
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TestHub>();
            context.Clients.All.broadcastMessage("Now", DateTime.Now.ToString());

            //test 2
            IHubContext context2 = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TestHub>();
            context2.Clients.All.Send("Now", DateTime.Now.ToString());

            //test 3
            TestHub.Send2("Now", DateTime.Now.ToString());

            string test = "";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting the user who clicked the button to receive this message? Have you seen what happens if you have two browsers opened on the same page and only one clicks the button?

Answer (score 0):

Methods on hubs to be called from clients need to be public- try switching from Internal to Public for Send2-